# Screen-scraping and SQL database

Tags: screen-scraping

I'm thinking of starting a small project involving screen-scraping various websites, the data of which I would like to store in an SQL database on the server.

I did this project a few years ago using C# and software called 'screen-scraper' which did most of the hard work for me, but I don't think this solution was as good as it could of been despite it working eventually so I would like to do it better this time. For reasons I can't remember now I could never run screen-scraper on the server and always had to leave another computer of my own on to do the scraping itself, then the data would be uploaded to the server from there..(maybe I was just being a moron).

I've heard very good things about Python and Beautiful Soup for this task although I've got no previous Python experience.

I would like ultimately everything to be able to run on the server side, so python script runs 24/7 on some server updating the SQL database with some frequency. Other code will also live on the server and be called upon by the user the manipulate the data from database etc.

I have more experience with C based languages, but I don't mind learning some Python if it's worth it. I just want to make sure I am heading in the right direction..

Comment: **SQL** is the Structured Query Language - a language used by many database systems - SQL is **NOT** a database product... stuff like this is very often vendor-specific - so we really need to know what database system you're using....

Comment: OK yeah sorry, I used SQL last time along with C# (I don't recall what type of database that was querying. I don't really mind what system I end up using, just as long as it can run on the server as I say and interact well with the language chosen to do the actual scraping...

Comment: fpghost, I see that you had a post regarding *Mathematica* deleted (because it was not an answer, but a further question).  If you would like help join us over on Mathematica.SE, specifically [Mathematica Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica).

Answer (score 0):

Python is good and probably the most popular choice for scraping. I would discourage beautiful soup though because it uses it's own syntax whereas lxml uses xpath which if you learn it will be useful in your c projects as well.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Would I be able to write some code in Python and let it run on a server, so basically scraping directly into their mySQL database, say, and using their bandwidth and CPU to execute the code. I want the content I scrape to be dynamically presented on some website table you see. So in summary I need 1) code able to execute on server like python script 24/7 running 2) this code able to write what it scrapes into that server's mySQL database say. You mention lxml, what about 'scrapy' would that be better to learn that beautiful soup?

Comment: Yes you can do all of that. Some people like scrapy, others find it not flexible enough. I recommend looking at source code of some python scrapers on scraperwiki.